# Money Order/Checks don't show on one page checkout in magento?

Tags: configuration, magento

I enabled Money Order / Checks in my magento 1.3.2.3 but it doesn't show in the one page checkout, I can't understand, Enable in the backend should be enough, right?

Ok given the comments I'm going to give you as much details as I can.

- Cache is disabled
- When I enabled another Payment Method, and click "Return, then Next" I can see the new payment method showed
- All countries is selected
- The Default Main Configuration is used over every Stores and Views

Comment: ...enabled at website/store/store-view levels?

Comment: I would have liked it was that, but it's not, using "default configuration" everywhere and set to "Yes"

Comment: What are your theme and interface names? My guess that you are using theme not in 'default' scope and module installs it's forms and layouts into /app/design/frontend/default/default

Comment: My theme is in design/frontend/default/COMPANYNAME/template/ etc. I also have a design/frontend/default/default/template

Comment: in this case my guess is wrong. if Magento can't find bankpayment template/layout in your theme folder it will look for it in default folder of your interface. Sure you amy try to copy bankpayment templates and layout to your folder to make sure but as i just told it have to work with default theme just fine.

Comment: I had a similar issue, but when I enabled the "Purchase Order" payment option as well, the "Check/Money Order" option started working also. Not sure why.

Comment: @Gordon, I finally found because of your comment, please consider add it as an answer I could accept, the app was developped by another dev who overrided the default template... and a f****g silent condition to bypass Check/MO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess that you are using theme not in 'default' scope and module installs its forms and layouts into /app/design/frontend/default/default